# Enable "run command prompt" shortcut in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut, italic

In Ubuntu System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts I can't enable the "run command prompt" shortcut neither the "show the activities overview" shortcut.

They are both in italics, unlike all other shortcuts.

The "run command prompt" shortcut is kinda important for my work. I've been searching all over the web, but can't find any solution.

I reinstalled Ubuntu, and now I can't enable these keys - was able to do that in previous installation.

[image]
Really hoping that someone has experienced the same problem as me, and has been able to solve the problem.

Comment: what version of ubuntu is that?

Comment: Note: Alt-PrtScr to capture a single window. Also, OT: you might want to learn how to manage the SO inbox flags and notification banners :)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I found out that those settings are forced to be disabled in Unity 2D. Editing this file: /var/lib/gconf/ubuntu-2d.mandatory/%gconf-tree.xml solved my problem. I just commented out everything inside < gconf > tags.

Answer (score 3):

Try change this using ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager).

```
$ ccsm
```

1. Click **'Gnome Compatibility'** (make sure that is enabled)
2. **'General'** tab:
3. Set desired hotkey for **'Run Dialog'** .

If you have installed a **'Ubuntu Unity Plugin'** bind hotkey using this plugin at 'Behaviour' tab.

Answer (score 2):

Erm...:

[image]

So, you click where it says *`Disabled`*, and you press the desired hotkey (usually, <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> for Run, e.g.)

Is that not working for you?

**PS.** if not, consider just adding custom shortcuts to do what you want. It may be you are using Unity, which might not readily implement these commands. You may consider switching to one of the 'old style' desktops that still support Gnome-style interface:

- Xubuntu (Xfce desktop, now with Linus endorsement :))
- Linux Mint 12
- Linux Mint Debian edition

Comment: Thanks man, still I can't edit the disabled "run command" shortcut, but I do see it's enabled by default.
However I need to change it, since I use Alt as a third level key for writing @ etc.

Comment: @Shuzheng: to enable it, click on the "Disabled" text (the prompt says "click the row" that works if you already have enabled the shortcut -- to change it)

Answer (score 2):

In the Keyboard settings dialog, if we click on the entire row as suggested on the dialog, it doesn't work. In fact, we must click on the **second column** indicating the value of the corresponding shortcut key (e.g., Disabled, Ctrl+Alt+D). This will allow us to edit or modify the new shortcut by entering the new keys.